# Why can't I convert an Excel file to an image using Spire.Xls in Linux?

Tags: c#, excel, spire.xls

I converted A Excel file to A Image In C# but i found that the API i used is Only for windows btw i am using linux

```
using Spire.Xls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace Convert
{
    class MainC
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.LoadFromFile("Test121.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013);
            Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
            
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                
                worksheet.ToEMFStream(ms, 1, 1, worksheet.LastRow, worksheet.LastColumn);
                Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                Bitmap images = ResetResolution(image as Metafile, 300);
                images.Save("Test121.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you contacted the company to see if the library you're using supports Linux?

Comment: is your project's target framework  .NET Core?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/excel-for-net-introduce/Features.html) says that the library should work with applications developed in wide range of .NET frameworks including .net core. What issue did you face when you tried to run this code on linux machine?

Comment: Granted, .Net Core or even [.NetStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.XLS/) doesn't mean it can run on Linux (example WinForms)

Comment: @Chetan when i executed the code it said The type or namespace name `Spire' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference. and i cant install it because it gives a msi installer btw i made a .cs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spire.XLS can be used on Linux. You do not need to install the msi, just [download](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-excel-for-net-now.html) the hotfix version which only contains DLLs:
[image]

Then reference the DLLs under the netcoreappX.0 folder into your net core project.
[image]

Comment: Btw, I'd suggest you install it via NuGet: PM> Install-Package Spire.XLS